# How to config dynamic link route in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have some confusion in routing.

We can config route in angular.config() while angular module is loaded.

That time we know how many to route means static(routePath, templateUrl,controller etc.).

But how to config the routes-templateurl-controller dynamically.For example:

I have certain list of features(nothing but links) which will come after user is logged in and based on the role assigned to it .

userfeatures=[{name:menu1,link:link1,...},{name:menu1,link:link1,...},{name:menu1,link:link1,...}...]

the above feature will come while the page will load for the first time( I am getting from controller which is called this time.)

Can we configure the route link dynamically?

How to get templateUrl when the link is clicked ,controller is processing and get the corresponding page?

What I tried(Actuallt its huge so only hint):

```
<body ng-app="myApp" >

<div ng-controller="c1" directive-to-show-menus-and-its-showing></div>    


<div ng-view></div>

<script>
var app = angular.module("myApp", ["ngRoute"]);

var $routeProvider1;

app.config(function($routeProvider) {
$routeProvider1=$routeProvider;
});

app.controller('c1',function($http,$route,$rootScope){

//var ar={"/":"main.htm","/red":"red.htm","/green":"green.htm","/blue":"blue.htm"};
var userfeatures=[{name:Red,link:red},{name:Green,link:green},{name:Blue,link:blue}]; //actually its huge

for(var i in userfeatures){

$routeProvider1.when("#!"+userfeatures[i].link,{
'templateUrl':'it should be dynamic', //(how to attach templateUrl in controller of its)
'controller':common_controller   //it would be good with dynamic controller
});

}

});

function common_controller(){
// how to get clicked link info to extract certain info.
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Better to have your code segmented to 3 segments:

1- Your application file (example: application.js)

2- Your routing file (example: Routing.js)

3- Your Url records (Url.json)

I will assume you have already configured your main controller and ready for the action.

Here a snap of how should your (Url.json) should look like:

```
{
"links" : [
{
    "Url": "/page/page1.html",
    "Controller": "Controller1"
},
{
    "Url": "/page/page2.html",
    "Controller": "Controller2"
}
]}
```

In your (Routing.js) file you should map the routes with the template files. You have to retrieve the data first from the json file through http request.

```
  Myapp.config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', '$locationProvider',
        function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $locationProvider) {
        });
Myapp.run(['$route', '$http', '$rootScope', function ($route, $http, $rootScope) {
    var url = 'mydirectory/Url.json';
    httpRequest.get(url).then(function (response) {

        if (response.statusCode == 200) {

            var result = data.links;

            for (i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
                $urlRouterProvider.when("/", {
                    templateUrl: result[i].Url
                });
            }
            $route.reload();
        }
    }, function () {
        console.log(Error!);
    });

}]);
```

In your (application.js) file you can rewrite the code of **common_controller()** and call it to update the json file (Url.json) based on your new dynamic link.

Comment: whatever json i am getting is only clickable link not the actual page.  Page should be got once i hit the link then from controller i supposed to get page and data as well.